# How to listen to a channel by it cid and get notified if the channel is available to a client

Tags: flutter, dart, getstream-io

### server side:

only server side is able to create channel, and add client user as a member of a channel. Every time it happens i need my client get notified and show hide him a view

### front side (flutter)

```
_subscription = client
        .queryChannels(
            filter: Filter.and([
          Filter.equal('id', cid),
          Filter.in_(
              'members', [userId])
        ]))
        .listen(_onChanged);
```

i used this query in order to listen for the channel that i need to access it, and show it only if i am a member of it

But even in the _onChanged callback method, my client get never notified if the channel is created or if it is available to him (because i am a member)

EDIT: client side it can works with

```
_subscription = client.on().listen(_onEvent);

void _onEvent(Event event) {
    if ((event.type == 'notification.added_to_channel' ||
            event.type == 'notification.removed_from_channel') &&
        event.channelId == targetId) {
      print('there');
      
    }
  }
```